# Why is JSON invalid when commas in string?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Anyone know why this JSON is invalid?

```
{"street_address":"Stone House Lane, Peckforton , Tarporley , London, Cheshire"}
```

I'm using Jackson for Java and it's complaining about

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:     Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6ad16fc1; line: 1, column: 405]
```

I noticed this JSON is considered invalid on this online site as well:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

**Answer: Thanks, for those who are curious I've removed these unreadable characters using tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file > cleanFile**

Comment: Could you please provide the entire snippet of code that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After copying/pasting your exact text, it shows as an invalid JSON variable. Then, I just copied/pasted the same content into a notepad (using Windows 7) and noted there are strange characters in your string (these characters cannot be seen in this page nor in web editors, so I'm using a blank space instead):

```
{"street_address":"Stone House Lane, Peckforton  , Tarporley  , London, Cheshire"}
                                               ^           ^
                                               here and here
```

I just removed them and worked as expected. Copy/paste it from here:

```
{"street_address":"Stone House Lane, Peckforton, Tarporley, London, Cheshire"}
```

---

After a more in-depth evaluation, the hexadecimal representation of this char is \u80A8.

Comment: thanks, for those who are curious I've removed these unreadable characters using tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file > cleanFile